# Javascript in wordpress

Tags: javascript

I have featured images shown for different posts of same category in a page in a specific div. I need to show the whole post related to this image in the same page in another div. I know i must use JavaScript in this. But i need some reference which i can use for this. Can anyone help me with this? I am using the following code to show the images

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Meet The Team Template
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="meet_posts" class="narrowcolumn">
<?php 
    $recent = new WP_Query("cat=6&orderby=title&order=ASC"); 
    while($recent->have_posts()):$recent->the_post();
    $desc_values = get_post_custom_values("description");

?>
<div id="meetteam_featured_image">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="title">
        <?php
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) 
            { 
                the_post_thumbnail();
            }
        ?>
    </a>
</div>
<?php endwhile ?>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to show all posts of all images or any specific post of specific image?

Comment: Specific post for specific image

Comment: Do you want to show post on clicking on image on the fly or do you want to display it when page gets loaded?

Comment: Clicking on the image

Comment: http://www.coreretirementsolutions.com/Meettheteam.php.  This is an example for what i need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your above code with this following code :

```
<?php /*
Template Name: Meet The Team Template
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="meet_posts" class="narrowcolumn">
<?php 
$recent = new WP_Query("cat=6&orderby=title&order=ASC"); 
while($recent->have_posts()):$recent->the_post();
$desc_values = get_post_custom_values("description");

?>
<div id="meetteam_featured_image" class="<?php the_ID(); ?> team_featured_image_<?php the_ID(); ?>">
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="title">
  <?php
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() )  { 
            the_post_thumbnail();
        }
    ?>
</a>
</div>
<?php endwhile ?>
<div id="image-post-info"></div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Add this following code in functions.php file :

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajaxified_function', 'ajaxified_function' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxified_function', 'ajaxified_function' );
function ajaxified_function() {   
   $temp = get_post($_POST['post_id']);
   echo $temp->post_title.'<br/><br/>'.$temp->post_content;   
   die();
}
```

Add this following code in your custom js file :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function (){       

 jQuery('#meetteam_featured_image a').on('click',function(event){         
 event.preventDefault();

 var post_id = jQuery(this).parent().attr('class');            
 post_id = post_id.split(" ");
 post_id = post_id[0];
 jQuery.ajax({  
   type: "POST",                  
   url:  'http://www.yoursitename.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',  
   data: 'action=ajaxified_function&post_id='+post_id,    
   success: function (msg) {                                        
      jQuery('#image-post-info').html(msg);
   },
   error: function () {                  
      alert('Error');                    
   }  
  });           
  });       
});
```

Add custom js file by including following code in functions.php file :

```
function add_custom_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/js/custom-scripts.js' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_custom_scripts' );
```

Comment: How will i add the custom js file to the code?

Comment: Thank you very much Vinod. I got more than what I needed. I owe you one.!!!! I have been stuck with this from yesterday. Thanks a lot...!!!!

Comment: Just more doubt. I want to change the class name which is named as <?php the_ID() ?> here. When i change it the content is not coming.What should i do to change it?

Comment: You can change it but you will have to include post id in it and you will also have to change some code. Tell me why do you want to change class name? what class name you want to display?

Comment: I just want to give some style to that. Thats why  need to change it.name can be any random name '

Comment: I have changed above code to make class name more useful.

Comment: This answer does not explain what was wrong with the original code, how it works, or what it does that the original didn't. It is purely copypasta and does not help anyone

Comment: There was nothing wrong with original code , i have changed it because @MidhuN wants me to add some different class name so in template file i have added one more class name team_featured_image_ and in custom js file i got the first class name by splitting class names.

Comment: Just one more help. I want to make the first post the default post without clicking on the image and when clicking the image also it should work.. what i need to change @VinodDalvi??

Comment: I am sorry if i am asking too much...!!!!! @VinodDalvi

Comment: I have done the Default post thing.One more thing is that i need to give style to some part of the post that is got when we click the image for example just for the heading of the post i need to give font-weight as bold.How can i do that? Now it is showing in a p tag when i check in firebug. Sorry If i am asking too much from you. I am just using the resource that i have got..!!!

Comment: You can change the markup in ajaxified_function whatever you want :  Example : ajaxified_function() {   
   $temp = get_post($_POST['post_id']);
   echo '<div class="meetteam_title">'.$temp->post_title.'</div><br/><br/>'.$temp->post_content;   
   die();
}

Comment: Thanks buddy..i was doing that only. anyway thanks...thanks a lot.!!!!

Comment: Can i get the featured image of the post also with the  above code which has been changed?

Comment: I have added the above mentioned thing. i have changed the ajaxified_function to 
`add_action('wp_ajax_ajaxified_function','ajaxified_function');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxified_function','ajaxified_function' );
function ajaxified_function() 
{ 
  $post = get_post($_POST['post_id']);
  $feat_image = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID);
  echo $feat_image.$post->post_.'<div class="meetteam_title">'.$post->post_title.'</div><br/>'.$post->post_content; 
  die();
}`